# How do I avoid using EVAL in a Repeater with VB.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, eval

I want to stop using EVAL everywhere in my code and remove it from all repeaters.  The project I am working on is in .NET 3.5.

I have this class

```
Public Class person
    Public Name As String
    Public Age As String
End Class
```

I am creating a `List(of person)` using a shared function.

I have a repeater where I am binding the `List(of person)` to it.

I have this code in the ItemTemplate portion of the repeater:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, person).Name %></td>
        <td><%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, person).Age %></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

When I try to run my code, it gives me this error message:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'person' to type 'person'.
  Source=App_Web_2uam_1hy
  StackTrace:
       at ASP.test_aspx.__DataBind__control4(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\test\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test.aspx:line 152
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
  InnerException:
```

Why can't I cast it to itself?  I'm sort of stumped here as all of the examples I can find online are for c#.  I'm sure it is something simple that I am missing, but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On your Repeater, set the [ItemType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemtype(v=vs.110).aspx). This allows you to have strongly typed data binding.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ItemType="person">
```

You may need to fully qualify the class name.

This allows you to do

```
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
    <td><%# Item.Name %></td>
    <td><%# Item.Age %></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Dang.  I don't have this as an option.  I am on .net 3.5.  I am going to update the question.  Thanks though.

Comment: @NinjaBomb In that case I would make upgrading from .NET 3.5 my highest priority.

Comment: It's on the list!  Thanks.

Comment: @NinjaBomb [This guy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18049/A-Typed-Repeater-in-ASP-NET) may have gotten it to work in a way that's compatible with older versions. If so, I would suggest you copy the relevant bits here as an answer.